# How can I make bash_history update more often?

Tags: bash

I'm often looking in my .bash_history file to see how I ran a program or exactly what arguments I used. The problem is that my history seems very incomplete. Some commands I'll find that I ran months ago, others I ran yesterday and aren't there. I think the issue is that I work over ssh a lot, and I'll often not log out cleanly, but rather be disconnected when my laptop sleeps or I move to a different wifi network. So it seems like bash only writes to the history file when it's exiting. Is this right? Is there a way I can force it write every command, or every few commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `history -a` to your `PROMPT_COMMAND` to update your saved history before each prompt.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

This should go in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Note that there was a bug in bash prior to bash-4.2-alpha which prevented this 'history -a' method from always working (for example, if you were starting with an empty $HISTFILE and `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a' `, $HISTFILE would not be updated as expected).  See the [original bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-08/msg00071.html).  This was fixed in bash-4.2-alpha (search for `history -a` within the [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/CHANGES?id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9) for a description of the fix.

Answer (score 3):

You could install [Advanced Shell History](https://github.com/barabo/advanced-shell-history), an open source tool that writes your `bash` or `zsh` history to a sqlite database.  This is a bit more extreme than simply including `history -a` in your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but it also records things like the current working directory, the command exit code, command start and stop times, session start and stop times, tty, etc.

If you want to query the history database, you can go so far as to write custom SQL queries and make them available to the bundled `ash_query` tool.  There are also a few useful prepackaged queries, but since I know SQL pretty well, I usually just open the database and write something custom when I need to look for something.

One command I find very useful, though, is looking at the history of the current working directory.  It helps me remember where I left off when I was working on something.

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ash_query -q CWD
session
    when                   what
1
    2014-08-27 17:13:07    ls -la
    2014-08-27 17:13:09    cd .ash
    2014-08-27 17:16:27    ls
    2014-08-27 17:16:33    rm -rf advanced-shell-history/
    2014-08-27 17:16:35    ls
    2014-08-27 17:16:37    less postinstall.sh
    2014-08-27 17:16:57    sudo reboot -n
```

And the same history using the current working directory (and anything below it):

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ash_query -q RCWD
session
    where
        when                   what
1
    /home/vagrant/advanced-shell-history
        2014-08-27 17:11:34    nano ~/.bashrc
        2014-08-27 17:12:54    source /usr/lib/advanced_shell_history/bash
        2014-08-27 17:12:57    source /usr/lib/advanced_shell_history/bash
        2014-08-27 17:13:05    cd
    /home/vagrant
        2014-08-27 17:13:07    ls -la
        2014-08-27 17:13:09    cd .ash
    /home/vagrant/.ash
        2014-08-27 17:13:10    ls
        2014-08-27 17:13:11    ls -l
        2014-08-27 17:13:16    sqlite3 history.db
        2014-08-27 17:13:43    ash_query
        2014-08-27 17:13:50    ash_query -Q
        2014-08-27 17:13:56    ash_query -q DEMO
        2014-08-27 17:14:39    ash_query -q ME
        2014-08-27 17:16:26    cd
    /home/vagrant
        2014-08-27 17:16:27    ls
        2014-08-27 17:16:33    rm -rf advanced-shell-history/
        2014-08-27 17:16:35    ls
        2014-08-27 17:16:37    less postinstall.sh
        2014-08-27 17:16:57    sudo reboot -n
```

FWIW - I'm the author and maintainer of the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Execute the following comands**

1. export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
2. shopt -s histappend
3. PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"

Note- You can add the above commands to .bash_profile file and reboot for permanent solution